# How to sort data of bind table in cakephp 2.0

Tags: cakephp-2.0, associated-sorting

I need the data from various table. I bind them by using cakephp's `$hasMany` variable. The data is fetched successfully. But I need to sort the result coming from `$hasMany` table.

for eg. I have two tables

- `Survey`
- `Questions`

Now `Survey` table contains the data related to Survey like `title`, `id`, `purpose` and `Questions` table contains question for related survey. I bind questions table with survey in survey model. Now I have a field in `Questions` table with name `ordering`. I need to fetch data in that order.

How can I fetch it in that way?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you want to sort the data directly when it is fetched from db**

You can define default order when adding relations between tables in your models. In your Survey model:

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Question' => array(
        'order' => 'ordering DESC'
    )
);
```

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany.

You can also define custom ordering when retrieving data from your controller in your conditional array, http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find:

```
$conditions = array(
    'order' => array('Question.ordering DESC')
);
```

If you are paginating your result with the *paginator component*, you can setup it like in following example book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#query-setup:

```
public $paginate = array(
    'order' => array(
       'Question.ordering' => 'desc'
    )
);
```

**If you want to sort the data presented in the view**

Here you can use the *pagination helper* (together with the *pagination component* in the controller) as:

```
echo $this->Paginator->sort('Question.ordering');
```

see book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#creating-sort-links

Sorry for removing 'http://' on the two last links, but I am not allowed to post more than two links (<10 rep).

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP you can sort by associated tables. but you need to sort by column, you should use something like this in your view:

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Question.ordering'); ?>
```